# Show one WooCommerce Product meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using one plugin for WooCommerce GST implementation. It has one HSN field inside product page which is stored in the database as the product meta.

The plugin does not have any specific code to get the HSN value and use it anywhere.

The code for HSN in the plugin is below:

```
public function fn_add_product_custom_meta_box() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'            => 'hsn_prod_id', 
            'label'         => __('HSN Code', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'description'   => __( 'HSN Code is mandatory for GST.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'custom_attributes' => array( 'required' => 'required' ),
            'value'         => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hsn_prod_id', true )
            )
        );
}

public function fn_save_license_field( $post_id ) {
    $value = ( $_POST['hsn_prod_id'] )? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['hsn_prod_id'] ) : '' ;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hsn_prod_id', $value );
}
```

I want to get the HSN value by importing it from product meta and I have used this code to get that without any result:

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hsn_prod_id', true ); ?>
```

Can anyone please check my code and correct me how to add the HSN value anywhere using the code?

I am using the code inside a different plugin to get the HSN code.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you using the get_post_meta function?  The function get_the_ID() might not return anything depending on where you are using the function.

Comment: The HSN is coming from a plugin and stored as product meta. I am calling it inside another plugin using the mentioned code. And you are right, it is not showing anything there.